# Cygwin setup over 100%

Tags: android, cygwin, installation, native

I'm having an issue with cygwin setup over 100% completed and its been running over about 3hrs. Im on a 10+Mbps connection and get about 1.2Mbps max actual download speed on average. But there is no end is sight with this setup. I understand after reading around that I should CHOOSE what I need first.

But after 3hrs of d/l I just wanna let it finish now because I'm not exactly and completely aware of each package I'll need in the end for android native C++ support.

Is there a way to add more mirrors while setup is still running/downloading?

If I 'cancel' (only button to choose) cygwin setup, will it continue later when I restart it? 
Will canceling it break the package its in the middle of downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you run Cygwin setup I recommend not installing any additional
packages. That is to say just hit <kbd>Next</kbd> through all the prompts. This
should only take [a couple of minutes](https://serverfault.com/a/409076). It will install just the basics, some listed below

```
bash                      4.1.10-4             OK
coreutils                 8.15-1               OK
gawk                      4.0.2-1              OK
grep                      2.6.3-1              OK
man                       1.6g-2               OK
sed                       4.2.1-2              OK
tar                       1.26-1               OK
```

After that you can go back and install extra packages.